# Google API Apps Script Function Execution Consistently Gets 500 Error

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I successfully obtain an access token and initialize the script service.  I have tried changing the scopes they are correct now.  Can you see the problem?  The result is this:

> GoogleJsonResponseException error response: null error: 500 Internal
>   Server Error {   "code" : 500,   "errors" : [ {
>       "domain" : "global",
>       "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
>       "reason" : "backendError"   } ],
>       "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
>       "status" : "INTERNAL" }

The code:

```
public static String replaceProjectDetail(String docTitle, String projectTitle, String customerName, String projectNumber) 
    throws GoogleDriveClientException, IOException, Exception {

            initialize_script();
            // ensure the properties were loaded
    if(!isInitialized) {
        throw new GoogleDriveClientException("Cannot process request because client objects are not initialized.");
    }

    final File content = getFileByTitle(docTitle);

            // ID of the script to call. Acquire this from the Apps Script editor,
            // under Publish > Deploy as API executable.
            String scriptId = SUPER SECRET SCRIPT ID;
            Object status = null;
            // Apps Script function to call.
            String functionName = "Function Name";
            String txtUrl = content.getWebViewLink();
            if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
               LOGGER.debug("Google file captured: " + content.getName() 
                        + ", url : " + txtUrl);
            }
            //isInitialized = false;
            //initialize_script();

            /** ensure the properties were loaded
    if(!isInitialized) {
        throw new GoogleDriveClientException("Cannot process request because client objects are not initialized.");
    }**/

            byte[] projNum = projectNumber.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] projTitle = projectTitle.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] custName = customerName.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] URL = txtUrl.getBytes("UTF-8");


            // Initialize parameters for that function.
            List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(projNum);
            params.add(projTitle);
            params.add(custName);
            params.add(URL);

            // Create execution request.
            ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest()
                .setFunction(functionName)
                .setParameters(params)
                .setDevMode(Boolean.FALSE);


            Credential client_credential = null;


            if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Google file apps script successfully configured.");
            }

            int high = 1000;
            Random r = new Random();
            int low = 1;

            // Attempt to execute our main action, retrying up to 4 times
            // if an exception is thrown
            for (int n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {
                try {

                    // The main action you want to execute goes here
                    // If this does not come in the form of a return
                    // statement (i.e., code continues below the loop)
                    // then you must insert a break statement after the
                    // action is complete.
                    // Make the API request.
                    client_credential = authorize();
                    //String accessToken = client_credential.getAccessToken();
                    /**if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())  {
                        LOGGER.debug("Google access token: " + accessToken);
                    }**/
                    op = service.scripts()
                            .run(scriptId, request)
                            .setAccessToken(client_credential.getAccessToken())
                            .execute();

                    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())  {
                        LOGGER.debug("Successfully executed function: " + op.toPrettyString());
                    }

                    Map<String,Object> response = (ExecutionResponse) op.getResponse();

                    status = response.get("result");

                    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())  {

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : response.entrySet()) {
                            if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                                LOGGER.debug("Google file apps script response:  entry.getKey()=" + entry.getKey().toString()
                                        + ", entry.getValue()=" + entry.getValue().toString());
                                return entry.getValue().toString();
                            } else if (entry.getValue() instanceof Class) {
                                LOGGER.debug("Google file apps script response: entry.getValue() = instance of Class.");
                                return "class";
                            } else {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Expecting either String or Class as entry value");
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        LOGGER.debug("Google file apps script executed successfully. Return value: " + status.toString());
                    }

                    return "success";
                    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {

                        String googleErrors = getScriptError(op);

                        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())  {
                            LOGGER.debug("GoogleJsonResponseException error response: " + googleErrors);
                        }

                        LOGGER.error("Failed to execute with error: " + e.getMessage());

                        // If we've exhausted our retries, throw the exception
                        if (n == 4) {
                            throw e;
                            }

                        // Wait an indeterminate amount of time (range determined by n)
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(((int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, n)) * 1000) 
                                + (r.nextInt(high - low) + low));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            // Ignoring interruptions in the Thread sleep so that
                            // retries continue
                        }
                    } catch (NullPointerException npe)  {
                        LOGGER.debug("NullPointerException error response: " + npe.getMessage());
                        // If we've exhausted our retries, throw the exception
                        if (n == 4) {
                            throw npe;
                            }

                        // Wait an indeterminate amount of time (range determined by n)
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(((int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, n)) * 1000) 
                                + (r.nextInt(high - low) + low));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            // Ignoring interruptions in the Thread sleep so that
                            // retries continue
                        }
                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ste)  {
                        LOGGER.debug("SocketTimeoutException error response: " + ste.getMessage());
                        // If we've exhausted our retries, throw the exception
                        if (n == 4) {
                            throw ste;
                            }

                        // Wait an indeterminate amount of time (range determined by n)
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(((int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, n)) * 1000) 
                                + (r.nextInt(high - low) + low));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            // Ignoring interruptions in the Thread sleep so that
                            // retries continue
                        } 
                } catch (SocketException se)  {
                        LOGGER.debug("SocketException error response: " + se.getMessage());
                        // If we've exhausted our retries, throw the exception
                        if (n == 4) {
                            throw se;
                            }

                        // Wait an indeterminate amount of time (range determined by n)
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(((int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, n)) * 1000) 
                                + (r.nextInt(high - low) + low));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            // Ignoring interruptions in the Thread sleep so that
                            // retries continue
                        } 
                    } catch (Exception ex)  {
                        LOGGER.debug("SocketException error response: " + ex.getMessage());
                        // If we've exhausted our retries, throw the exception
                        if (n == 4) {
                            throw ex;
                            }

                        // Wait an indeterminate amount of time (range determined by n)
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(((int) Math.round(Math.pow(2, n)) * 1000) 
                                + (r.nextInt(high - low) + low));
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            // Ignoring interruptions in the Thread sleep so that
                            // retries continue
                        } 
                    }

                }

        return "success";
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your code. It is a wonder you even got it in there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1)  An Apache Tomcat web service that searches for a Google Doc
2)  Get it's url
3)  Initialize the script service
4)  create a Google API Apps Script Function Execution which
         a)  searches for a document with the url
         b)  replaces text on the google document which is a copy of a template
5)  logs the error

It is programmed with retry of up to 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not this code.  I did not realize you had to use the same credential to start the Script service and get the access token for the Google API Apps Script Function Execution.